# Why generating energy from the gravity side (air column) in a buoyancy chain machine isn’t possible?

Tags: energy-conservation, fluid-statics, buoyancy, dissipation, perpetual-motion

[image: ![enter image description here]

(For simplicity let’s say that just 1 ball will be rotating into the machine.)

It's proven that in a buoyancy chain machine the needed energy to submerge the ball into the water column will be (theoretically) equals to the energy that can be generated from the ball going up to the top of the water column. Which will leave us with zero net energy from the waterside.
A buoyancy chain machine is considered a Perpetual motion machine. **But I see if we harvest all the potential energy from the gravity side. The process will end up with surplus energy from the gravity side (air side)!**

I don’t find a reason why this won't work? Please explain why my theory will not work.

Comment: You need energy to submerge the balls that come back into the water, how do you push them into it?

Comment: The accepted answer in your linked question explains why your idea doesn't work. At the bottom of the machine, the water pressure is greater than the air pressure. Therefore *you have to do work against the pressure difference*, to move the ball from the air to the water. That cancels out the work you get back as the ball rises to the top of the machine.

Comment: I just realized you included a link with the answer, why then did you post the question again?

Comment: Gravity is the same on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

the balls going through the hole in the bottom of the cavity experience the pressure of the water at that depth, which opposes their passage through the hole and into the water. It takes work to pull them through the hole. The pressure at that depth cancels the buoyancy force of the (rising) immersed balls on the right, and the machine generates no net force on the ball system and the machine does not generate any free energy.

Comment: Perpetual machines are impossible. This kind of resembles it. But I have a question. Assume we cut the rope at the top. As there are more balls submerged in water on the right side, wouldn't the buoyancy force be higher on that side and make the wheel underwater rotate counter-clockwise? Pushing the ball on the left side into water at that pressure is difficult but do we not balance this force by another ball on the right side ?